# Can't see Android SDK Option when installing to use with Unity 3D

Tags: android, sdk

I download Android studio and would like to use with my Unity 3D projects. When I begin installing it doesn't show me **Android SDK Option**.

[image: Can't see Android SDK option...]

I hope to find some answer.

Thank you,
Waqas

Comment: is it the actual android studio installation or the add on tool provided by unity?Meaning - did you click the android sdk option in unity abd then downloaded it?

Comment: Ah actually not. But it took me to the same page, I wonder if it will enable the option.